# Obtencion de token al hacer login en Firebase/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, typescript

Este es mi codigo:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app"


@Injectable()

export class LoginService{

token: string;

constructor(private router: Router){}
    
    login(email: string, password: string){
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).
        then(
            response => {
                firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken().then(
                    token=> {
                        this.token = token;
                        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
                    }
                    )
                }
                )
            }
            
            getIdToken(){
                return this.token;
            }
        }
```

El error lo marca en firebase.auth().currentUser haciendo que no se pueda cargar la pagina ya que el error en la sintaxis dice que el objeto es nulo, pero intenté ponerle un signo ? o ! al final de currentUser lo cual hacía que los errores de sintaxis desaparecieran, sin embargo aparecian errores en la consola de Chrome viendose así:

```
ERROR TypeError: firebase_compat_app__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.auth is not a function
    at LoginService.login (login.service.ts:14)
    at LoginComponent.login (login.component.ts:20)
    at LoginComponent_Template_form_ngSubmit_1_listener (login.component.html:2)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15308)
    at Object.wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault [as next] (core.js:15346)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at EventEmitter_.next (Subject.js:39)
```

¿Cuál sería la sintaxis correcta en este caso?

Comment: prueba reemplazar `firebase.auth().currentUser` por `response.user`

Comment: No funcionó, marca aun mas errores.

Comment: estás haciendo una migración o es un proyecto nuevo? Por qué importas la versión compat??

Comment: Es un proyecto nuevo. Y uso la version compat porque es la unica manera en donde no me marca errores en el import de firebase ademas de marcarme errores en auth, token y response.

Comment: Pero la versión compat es para mantener compatibilidad con proyectos existentes, no deberías usarla si es el proyecto nuevo. Intenta seguir el ejemplo de la [documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password) y si te da errores colócalos en la pregunta

Comment: Pero es que como dije, si yo pongo import firebase from "firebase/app" pues me sale error en el firebase despues del import y para que no me salga ese error agrego * as firebase. La cosa es que al hacer eso los errores se marcan en auth, response y token.

Comment: Es que no tienes que hacer ese import. Que ejemplo estás siguiendo? Mira el que dice v9

Comment: En cuanto a los ejemplos que hay en la documentación, realmente no sé como combinarlo con la sintaxis que tengo para que funcione bien. ¿Cómo lo haría usted de acuerdo a lo que ha visto hasta ahora?